# Getting Error while clicking on a button in Orbeon Form

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am getting an error which is not expected as per the code.

This is the error i am getting.

```
Attempting to access a sequence as a singleton item (org.orbeon.saxon.trans.XPathException)
```

This is my Add button Code:

```
<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" id="repeat-add-id" ref=".[$summary='false' and instance('abc-instance')/product/accounts]">
    <xforms:label>
        <span class="input-label">Add</span>
    </xforms:label>
    <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xforms:insert nodeset="instance('abc-instance')/product/accounts[last()&lt;10]"
            origin="instance('abc-instance-template')/product/accounts" />
        <!-- <xforms:message modal="level">Xforms Message</xforms:message> -->
</xforms:trigger>
```

This is my summary variable defnition

```
<xxforms:variable name="summary" select="instance('abc-attributes')/form-global/summary"/>
```

If i remove the insert command in `<xforms:action>` it will not show the error dialog box.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `instance(abc-instance)` in the `ref` of the trigger looks wrong. Most likely you need quotes as in `instance('abc-instance')`. Also the `accounts[last() < 10]` looks strange to me; what are trying to do there? Sorry but I can't be more specific without being able run your code.

Comment: yeah, the instance name requires quotes. I modified it. However i found the actual problem, please see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. There is nothing wrong with the code in the trigger itself. I am using `xxforms:valid()` for the nodeset `instance('abc-instance')/product/accounts` in later part of code. On the first run, since there is only one node, and so there are no errors. However When I click add button link, there are 2 nodes, but the `xxforms:valid()` expects a single node, hence the error message.

**Summary:**

So the bottom line here is, when you see this error ***"Attempting to access a sequence as a singleton item***", that means there are some functions in your form which are expecting a single node are parameter but there exists more than one.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. There are plans to improve the reporting of errors to have a better indication of the expression in which the error happened, and where that expression was located.

Comment: Thanks Avernet. That will be much helpful to debug an issue.